# Compression for Dask on disk shuffle

Tags: compression, bigdata, out-of-memory, dask, shuffle

Currently I am working on a Dash local cluster on a set of lz4 compressed Parquet files.
Reading and writing compressed files works fine but when setting and index the shuffle algorithm will write a lot of uncompressed data to the disk (data is larger than my memory so I use out-of-memory shuffling on the disk).

Shuffling in Dask is done with the **partd** project which itselfs supports compression with snappy or lz4. However, I am not able to activate compression for the local workers and shuffle files.
Is there any way using enviroment variables or dask.settings?

Many thanks

```
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.distributed import Client

# setup local cluster
client = Client(n_workers=2, threads_per_worker=4, processes=False, memory_limit='16GB')

# load, set index, save
df = dd.read_parquet('Data/Parquet', engine='fastparquet')  # <-- is compressed
df2 = df.set_index(use_columns, shuffle='disk')  # <-- generates a lot of uncompressed data on the disk
df2.to_parquet('Data/ParquetSorted', engine='fastparquet', compression="lz4")  # <-- again compressed
```

Edit: feature has been implemented in the meantime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just took a quick look at the code and it looks like the answer today is "No.  This is hard coded."  That could be changed, but it requires some technical discussion.  I encourage you to raise an issue at https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/new